# AWS CodePipeline Fails - Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

This was working perfectly fine - all of a sudden I do a push and suddenly my pipeline is failing consistently. <s>The code works fine locally so have no idea what triggered this all of a sudden.</s> This is the execution output where it says it failed:

```
Compiling @alyle/ui/menu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @alyle/ui/themes/minima : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/clipboard : es2015 as esm2015
An error occurred during the build:
Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.
    at Object.resolveTypeReferenceDirective (/codebuild/output/src882534748/src/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:42530:18)
    at /codebuild/output/src882534748/src/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/host.js:165:35



    at Array.map (<anonymous>)



    at Object.host.resolveTypeReferenceDirectives (/codebuild/output/src882534748/src/web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/host.js:164:32)



    at actualResolveTypeReferenceDirectiveNamesWorker (/codebuild/output/src882534748/src/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:116611:163)



    at resolveTypeReferenceDirectiveNamesWorker (/codebuild/output/src882534748/src/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:116911:26)



    at processTypeReferenceDirectives (/codebuild/output/src882534748/src/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118393:31)



    at findSourceFileWorker (/codebuild/output/src882534748/src/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118278:21)



    at findSourceFile (/codebuild/output/src882534748/src/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118133:26)



    at processImportedModules (/codebuild/output/src882534748/src/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118539:25)



    at findSourceFileWorker (/codebuild/output/src882534748/src/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118284:17)
    at findSourceFile (/codebuild/output/src882534748/src/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118133:26)
    at processImportedModules (/codebuild/output/src882534748/src/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118539:25)
    at findSourceFileWorker (/codebuild/output/src882534748/src/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118284:17)
    at findSourceFile (/codebuild/output/src882534748/src/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118133:26)
    at processImportedModules (/codebuild/output/src882534748/src/web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118539:25)
An unhandled exception occurred: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.

See "/tmp/ng-PiwkC7/angular-errors.log" for further details.
[Container] 2022/05/30 16:09:49 Command did not exit successfully ng build --source-map=false exit status 127



[Container] 2022/05/30 16:09:49 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED



[Container] 2022/05/30 16:09:49 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: ng build --source-map=false. Reason: exit status 127
[Container] 2022/05/30 16:09:49 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2022/05/30 16:09:49 Running command mkdir ppartifact

[Container] 2022/05/30 16:09:49 Running command cp -a web/dist/. ppartifact/
cp: cannot stat 'web/dist/.': No such file or directory
[Container] 2022/05/30 16:09:49 Command did not exit successfully cp -a web/dist/. ppartifact/ exit status 1
[Container] 2022/05/30 16:09:49 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2022/05/30 16:09:49 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: cp -a web/dist/. ppartifact/. Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2022/05/30 16:09:49 Expanding base directory path: ppartifact
[Container] 2022/05/30 16:09:49 Assembling file list
[Container] 2022/05/30 16:09:49 Expanding ppartifact
[Container] 2022/05/30 16:09:49 Skipping invalid file path ppartifact
[Container] 2022/05/30 16:09:49 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED
[Container] 2022/05/30 16:09:49 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching base directory path found for ppartifact
```

This is an angular based site - it was working fine - I havent installed any new dependencies. What could the issue be?

UPDATE---

OK my bad - the code is broken locally as well. The error message I'm getting is pretty much the same - I've tried to downgrade angular and tsc but nothing much has happened. Whats the best course of action here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - apparently ended up downgrading my typescript to 4.5.5

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading ts-node to 2.0.0 solved the problem here.